# Jquery: Convert Arraylist to Array

Tags: jquery

How to convert string to array?

[image]

How to parse it in JQuery?

Server Side Code:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/getjobsbypartno/{jobno}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Long> getjobsbypartno(@PathVariable("jobno") String jobNo) {
        return getAllByPartNumber(jobNo);
    }


documentCommon.ajax({
                    dataType : 'text',
                    url : "/getjobsbypartno/"+$("#partNo").val(),
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {
                        '_CONV_ID': $('input[name="_CONV_ID"]').val()
                    },
                    success : function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        if(data != null){
                            console.log(data);
                            console.log(data[0]);
                            console.log(data[1]);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: The code you've shared is Java and it sends JSON back to the browser. jQuery should parse JSON automatically if data comes from an AJAX request. Can you please share the JavaScript code rather than the server-side code?

Comment: On a side note, it's suspicious that a part number comes as `Long`. Make sure it's actually meant to be a number and not a numeric string (i.e., is it `1234` or `00001234`?).

Comment: Remove `dataType : 'text'`. It isn't text, it's JSON.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: Updated code in description

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: Yes it worked after removing datattype